# How can I make my while loop run correctly?

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

My code is supposed to ask the user to input a number between 1 and 10. If they input a number between 1 and 10, then it will say thank you and end there. If not, it should loop and say, Please input a number between 1 and 10, and Please try again. It will then make the user input again. My problem is that after the second input, it automatically ends the loop even if they make an incorrect input the second time. By the way, I am very new to coding so please go easy on me in the comments XD. Someone, please help, thanks.
Here is my code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoopLecture {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int MIN = 1;
        int MAX = 10;
        String rating;
        rating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your rating of Krabbypatties on a scale of" 
                + MIN + "to" + MAX + ".With" + MIN + "meaning youhated it and" + MAX + "meaning you loved it.");
        int rating2 = Integer.parseInt(rating);
        while (rating2 < MIN || rating2 > MAX) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a value between " + MIN + "and" + MAX + ".");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again.");
            rating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your rating of Krabbypatties on a scale of" 
                    + MIN + "to" + MAX + ".With" + MIN + "meaning youhated it and" + MAX + "meaning you loved it.");
            if (rating2 >= MIN && rating2 <= MAX)
                break;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you!");
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, consider to try to improve the formatting of your code that you post in here and your code in general. Good formatting including using an indentation style that is uniform and consistent will help others (**us**!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, it will help **you** to better understand your code and thus fix your own bugs. Also it shows that you're willing to put in extra effort to make it easier for the volunteers here to help you, and that effort is **much** appreciated.

Comment: You never parse `rating` for `rating2` **in** your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Within for loop try assigning the new value to the rating2

rating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your rating of Krabby

---

rating2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your rating of Krabby

Comment: When I do this, it now says cannot convert from string to int.

Comment: @Safranek03 JOptionPane.showInputDialog() return String value. May be it should be ` rating2 = Integer.parseInt(rating)`. Also you should validate the input value is a number or not.

Comment: @Botale I tried ` rating2 = Integer.parseInt(rating) ` in the loop, but it said that it was now a duplicate variable. How would I validate the input value as a number or not? Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions, I just started learning to code about a week ago.

Comment: @Safranek03 Don't define a variable twice. Use regexp or only catch NumberFormatException to validate it

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) { // creates infinite while loop


break; // ends an infinite loop


}
```

You have a `break;` expression in your if statement, so I'm sure you understand how it works, but try just making the loop infinite, like shown above.

Comment: Thank you guys all for the help, I finally figured it out. I created a string names rating3 converted it to an int which was named rating4 and substituted rating4 into the if statement before the break!

Comment: @Safranek03 Be careful with defining one time variables, in small systems it might not be noticiable, but defining a new variable takes some of the processing power of the system. As it seems you might be better of to immeadiatly parsing/converting to `int` since you only use the input as an `int` rather than using 2 extra variables for it. This also makes it easier to understand, since you only need to use one name, and don't need to remember which of the 4 variables with the same name was what

Answer (score 0):

more better may to solve it:

1. parse `rating` to `rating2` in loop
2. break if number between 1 and 10
3. catch `NumberFormatException`, no need do anything, just ignore it

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int MIN = 1;
    int MAX = 10;
    String rating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your rating of Krabbypatties on a scale of"
            + MIN + "to" + MAX + ".With" + MIN + "meaning youhated it and" + MAX + "meaning you loved it.");
    while (true) {
        try {
            int rating2 = Integer.parseInt(rating);
            if (rating2 >= MIN && rating2 <= MAX) {
                break;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a value between " + MIN + "and" + MAX + ".");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please try again.");
        rating = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your rating of Krabbypatties on a scale of"
                + MIN + "to" + MAX + ".With" + MIN + "meaning youhated it and" + MAX + "meaning you loved it.");
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you!");
}
```